# Let $(G, ∗)$ be a finite abelian group and $G=\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$. Let $a_1∗a_2∗···∗a_n=x$. Show that $x∗x=e$, where $e$ is the identity of $(G, ∗)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

> Let $(G, ∗)$ be a finite abelian group and $G = \{a_1, a_2, . . . , a_n\}$. Let $a_1 ∗a_2 ∗· · · ∗a_n = x$. Show that $x ∗ x = e$, where $e$ is the identity of $(G, ∗)$.

Please give me head start on how to proceed. I am completely blank.

Comment: Every element of a group has an inverse.

Comment: Every element has an inverse.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: what's the use of this property here? I am sorry if I am asking dumb questions.I am novice in algebra.

Comment: You just had a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3548844/let-g-∗-be-a-group-and-a-b-c-∈-g-show-that-there-exists-a-unique-eleme). Try to improve with the posts.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=a_1\ast\dots \ast a_n$. Since $(G, \ast)$ is a group, each $a_i$ has an inverse $a_{j_i}$ in $G$ with respect to $\ast$ for some $j_i$. Because inverses are unique, we have a bijection between $\{a_i\mid i\in\{1, \dots, n\}\}$ and $\{a_{j_i}\mid j_i\in\{1, \dots, n\}\}$ given by taking inverses. Thus the product that is $x$ is equal to the product of all the inverses $a_{j_i}$ of each $a_i$. But $(G, \ast)$ is abelian. Thus we can reason as follows:

$$x^2=(a_1\ast\dots\ast a_n)\ast\color{red}{(a_1\ast\dots \ast a_n)},$$

so we can move each of the inverses $\color{red}{a_{j_i}}$ to the left until they are paired off with their respective $a_i$, like this:

$$\begin{align}
x^2&=(a_1\ast\dots\ast a_n)\ast\color{red}{(a_{j_1}\ast\dots \ast a_{j_n})}\\
&=(a_1\ast \color{red}{a_{j_1}})\ast\dots\ast(a_n\ast \color{red}{a_{j_n}}),
\end{align}$$

meaning that $x^2$ is the product of pairs of elements with their inverses, which are each equal to the identity $e$. Hence $x^2=e.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Among the factors in the product $a_1\times a_2\times\cdots\times a_n$ is each element and its inverse,

unless the element is its own inverse.  An element times its inverse is the identity.

Answer (score 0):

In any group $a^{-1}=b^{-1} \iff a=b$. Hence the set $G=\{a_1, a_2, . . . , a_n\}=\{a_1^{-1}, a_2^{-1}, . . . , a_n^{-1}\}$.

Therefore since $(G,*)$ is abelian $x^{-1}=(a_1 ∗a_2 ∗· · · ∗a_n)^{-1}=a_n^{-1} ∗a_{n-1}^{-1} ∗· · · ∗a_1^{-1}=a_1 ∗a_2 ∗· · · ∗a_n=x$.